Are backstab receptacles all that bad?
I have heard many people here recommend, sometimes very strongly, not to use backstab outlets, switches, etc, or at least not to use those connections if screw connections are available.  Reasons given is that those connections do not hold up well over time, become intermittent or develop high resistance, etc.
But, are they really that bad?  Reason I bring this up is that I just pulled the switches from a 3-gang box that has been in place for over 40 years (the condo was built in 1983), and they all used back stab connections.  And as far as I know there has never been an issue.
Here's a picture.  The screw terminals are on the far side of the switch and not visible in this picture.
So are backstabs really that bad?


More of being the weakest link of connection.  Most are a thin edge piece of metal using a spring to hold the wire.  They should also be a single use only, but some people will reuse them.

Note that higher quality switches/outlets do have a wire clamp method that is safe and reliable, but it's not backstab.  The proper technique for these side clamp devices is to strip the wire to the proper depth, insert it underneath the clamp plate, and then tighten the screw down to the proper torque, clamping the wire between the device and the clamp plate.  Personally I still would loop around the screw because I'm old-school in my technique, but the clamp method is perfectly long-term safe.

I don't use them but if my whole house had been wired with them and I wasn't having any issues then I wouldn't go through the work to pull all the devices and rewire them.

Just FYI there are some "more modern" switches with wago type connection options in them that might be more trustworthy? :)

Everything I see here is opinions and anecdotes.  What do the manufacturers have to say? A better question is, how are they allowed to sell such things if they carry a significant risk?

It should be noted that this not only depends on the quality of the connector but also on the countries power system, as with 240V you have half the current, thus this is so much of a non-issue that most outlets and switches there have that as the only way to connect.

@PlasmaHH are there 240V countries with push-in connectors built in to electrical outlets?  I'd like to see them.

While the consensus is that they have a higher fail rate than screw clamps, "that bad" is not objectively assessable. VTC as opinion-based.

@jay613 Pretty common in Europe. I'm in the Netherlands and just last week I had to fix a switch with a loose wire. My uncle had removed the cover of the switch to better paint around it and the switch had popped out of the box (was never secured properly in the first place I guess). 1 wire popped out. He couldn't figure out in which hole it was originally attached (old and new wiring with different color-coding in the same box was confusing) so he called me in to fix it. I just pushed it back in. They are pretty solid IF pushed in far enough. This one originally wasn't fully in I think.

The idea of a push connector with a spring for a contact is not "bad".  There are dozens of companies making hundreds of wire nuts that are the same as "backstabs" in general principle.  It is possible that the backstab connectors used in American $1 switches are inferior, or that they are used incorrectly, or that they tend to be used by non-professionals, who, if they used the screw terminals, would have an even worse track record.   I have no data but I suspect that a professional doing new construction and using backstabs properly will have about the same failure rate as one using screws.

@jay613 here in germany the majority of the good brands have push in connectors. According to DIN VDE 0620 they are good for 16A. Chances are they work a bit differently to pass these standards than in other countries.

@PlasmaHH  "they work differently" is one way to say it.  There are good push connectors in the USA as well.  But the ones electricians hold in contempt were made for a specific purpose (low cost and fast one-time installation by trained professionals) but ended up being used more broadly, because to an untrained person they seem easier.  IMO, an untrained person using a good screw terminal poorly will have roughly the same amount of failures later.  I've never seen data though, only hot opinions, and the fact is manufacturers are  still allowed to make the cheap kind and they have data.

@jay613 I have no idea how that works in other countries, but here they must pass certain tests to be allowed to be sold

Backstabs are really bad when used with high currents.
The inherent higher resistance in the backstab connector promotes heating when under load. Heat promotes oxidation. Oxidation worsens the contact resulting even more heat. Heat also reduces the spring force, leading to more resistance and more heat and so on - all the way to losing the electrical connection (the good case) or starting a fire.
In a switch that powers only a few lightbulbs, the heat produced in the contact is simply not enough to start the above sequence and the backstab is good for decades.

That all makes sense, and appears to be my case.  While the wiring is 12 gauge (protected by a 20 A breaker), the switches are only controlling a light or two or, in one case, a bathroom fan.

I've seen as many smoked switches as outlets when it comes to backstab damage.  Loading definitely isn't the only issue with them.

Yes ...Backstabs are bad.
I am biased, because I had to waste time hunting down an odd problem with my microwave. The cable to the outlet in the cabinet was run to another outlet in a different cabinet used for a trash compactor. The wires were backstabbed into the back of that outlet.
The whole thing caused my micro to run for about 5 seconds, then lose power.  Wait 5 minutes or so and the power came back.
Backstabs are a known issue, so why take a chance. Just spend the extra two minutes and put wires under the screws.

Just because you have not personally noticed an issue in your particular unit does not mean it's a good practice.
Backstab connections, in general, have looser connections than using the screws. A loose connection can cause heat and arcing - neither are good.
Here's another anecdotal take for you - my condo is 12 years old and all my outlets only support backstab connections.  Several outlets were so loose that the plug had to be jiggled for the device to get power.  I replaced them all and no longer have to worry about them melting or starting a fire due to a loose connection.
As others had said - spend the extra two minutes per outlet/switch and use the screws.  If the outlet/switch does not have screws, they are cheap - like $6 for a 10 pack.

There's one major rule in electrical work this violates: movement.
Voltage is a measure of how much "electrical pressure" there is. A 1.5v battery is harmless to the touch because your body isn't a great conductor at lower voltages. But at higher voltages (which includes 120v) there's enough pressure that it will jump gaps. We call this arcing, and arcing is how you turn electricity into fire (i.e. spark plugs and combustion engines).
Backstabs are quick and easy, but they are notorious for losing the physical connection. Why? I'll borrow an image from this answer

Note what holds the backstab. This is a modern backstab, with what amounts to a brass claw. I've seen some old ones use nothing more than a glorified spring. This can provide a poor mechanical connection, especially if the device was moved a lot (i.e. an owner pulling them all out to take a picture for a DIY site...). Every movement of the wire can weaken the connection. So, as long as you never move the device, and you don't have a lot of big temperature fluctuations, you can be fine. But do you really want to trust a folded piece of metal in a device designed to be as cheap as possible to hold up?
You'll note the premium outlet next to it. It uses what I call a "side stab". The goal of "stabs" in general is to not go through the hassle of making a shepherd's hook and wrapping it around a screw (which has its own headaches). That system, despite being frustrating, will at least tell you when you failed because the wire pops out from underneath the screw. Side stabs are even better because you put the wire under a plate and then screw the plate down. No headaches with bending wire and making sure it stays in place.
